# Visual Studio 15.7.1 Typescript debugger not breaking

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

Since upgrading to VS 15.7.1 Typescript debugging does not work.  Create new project - Select Typescript - Use all the defaults and add a breakpoint at the first line (e.g. var el = xxx in the code below.

```
window.onload = () => {
    var el = document.getElementById('content');
    var greeter = new Greeter(el);
    greeter.start();
};
```

The code works, TS generate the JS files and it runs just fine, but the Typescript breakpoint is not hit.

Is there a setting in the new version that I'm not aware of to enable debugging in Visual Studio rather than the JS in which ever browser I'm running?

Note I'm trying to debug with the default IIS Express (Microsoft Edge) browser.

Thanks

Comment: you can add `debugger;` on a new line and if you have the dev. console open in the browser debugging will break at that point.

Comment: it will break in the browser and not in Visual studio if I attach the browsers development tools.  This does not address the question.  Visual Studio has an integrated debugger and that is what I want to enter when the breakpoint is hit.

Answer (score 0):

This was a failure in trying to use MS Edge browser.  Evidently Microsoft has yet to provide the hook necessary to use the Edge browser for debugging in Visual Studio.  I thought that perhaps they would have gotten this done since the default browser to run a Type Script project in VS 2017 is IIS Express(Edge). It was unfortunate that I spent so long on trying to find a solution to this.